# EC2 instance - Unable to use EBS volume

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have EC2 instance(Ubuntu) in Amazon EC2. I have attached 200GB EBS volume to my instance (t2.micro).

The space status of my instance as per `df -h` command are:

```
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.7G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  364K   99M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdf       197G  7.9G  179G   5% /data
```

It clearly telling `/dev/xvda1` is full. But my instance not using attached EBS volume, hence my application server is not running. Please help me to resolve this issues.

Note: I have tried to swap (8GB) from EBS to my instance so that the device `/dev/xvdf` telling 5% used. But it never used by my instance.

Comment: what is the output of `lsblk`

Comment: The lsblk details
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0     8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0     8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0   200G  0 disk /data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/dev/xvda1 seems to be your bootvolume, this usually defaults to 8GB when you start a new linux instance unless you change the default value.

/dev/xvdf is an additional 200GB volume you have attached to the instance, this is different to the boot volume.

The EC2 instance will not automatically use the 200GB non-boot volume. *You* have to use it-- mount it, format it, move files off the boot volume to this volume if you want.

If you'd rather have a larger boot volume see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I resolved my issues as per your direction.